# Update progress bar in VB.NET using action delegate

Tags: c#, vb.net

I use this C# code to update the progress bar on a winform from another thread:

```
progressBar1.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value = someinteger));
```

What would be its exact equivalent in VB.NET?

When I click a button on a winform, it runs a function asynchronously.
This is the whole code, I tried the above 2 answers, but it didn't work.

```vb
Sub heavy_task()

    For j = 0 To 1000000

        ' some heavy task
        Dim percentdone As Integer = (100 * (j + 1)) / 1000000

        ' program not moving forward with this
        ' ProgressBar1.Invoke(New Action(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = percentdone))

        ' this updates the progressbar once the for loop completes and not on each iteration
        'ProgressBar.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = percentdone )


    Next

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim t1 As Tasks.Task
    t1 = New Tasks.Task(Sub() heavy_task())
    t1.Start()
    t1.Wait()
    MessageBox.Show("task complete")
End Sub
```

(I would like to apologise for not providing the whole code.)

Comment: progressBar1.Invoke(Sub() progressBar1.Value = someinteger) for example.

Comment: thank you for answering my question.

Comment: It catches my eye you had it commented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
ProgressBar.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = newvalue)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
progressBar1.Invoke(New Action(Sub() progressBar1.Value = someinteger))
```

Comment: An explanation would be great to understand what the issue was here and to further validate your solution. If I was coming along to look for a solution, this answer doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: The question and the answer should be self-explanatory. What kind of explanation are you looking for when the question is "what would be its exact equivalent in VB.NET?"?

Comment: `I tried the above 2 answers, but it didn't work`, I believe I would address this in my answer. Clearly it's not as it's not working for the OP.

Comment: @mm8 no, what I meant was the OP post at top, not your answer. You asked `What kind of explanation are you looking for when the question is...` I was trying to explain, there should be an explanation as to *why* it wasn't working for the op :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Did you read the original question? Read it again. The OP asks how to do the equivalent of calling Invoke in C# in VB.NET. Besides, he has accepted an answer and closed the question.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for taking the time to answer my silly question
Because i was already running the function asynchronously,
i just needed to use this code

> ProgressBar1.Value = percentdone

Thank you.

Comment: That can't be right. Your code isn't run asynchronously; it's run in a _Task_, meaning it's being executed in a different thread than the UI thread. The part of your code that's updating the progress bar should throw an InvalidOperationException without the use of `Invoke()`.

Comment: yes, you are right, I made mistake again, i noticed it just now.
Because of the progressbar not updating, i ran the function synchronously. and that is y it was working and not giving errors :|

Comment: So how should i run the function asynchronously and also update the progressbar ?

Comment: If each iteration is too fast then the progress bar will not have time to redraw itself before the next update. If this is the case you'd be better off storing the progress in a class-level variable and update the progress bar via a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which polls that variable (when doing this you also don't need to call `Invoke`, since the timer already runs on the UI thread).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, after searching and trying for hrs, decided to do it like this.
my thanks to everyone for helping :)

> Sub heavy_task()
>
> ```
> For j = 0 To 1000000
>
>     ' some heavy task
>     Dim percentdone As Integer = (100 * (j + 1)) / 1000000
>
>     ProgressBar.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = percentdone )
>
> Next End Sub
> ```
>
> Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
>   Button1.Click
>
> ```
> Dim thread1 As New Thread(AddressOf heavy_task)
>     thread1.Start()
>
>
> If thread1.IsAlive = False Then            
>         MessageBox.Show("task complete")
>     End If
> ```
>
> End Sub